# How to hide the sidebar when we touch anywhere on the screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have created a custom sidebar because it was needed for a client request i am able to toggle the side bar on press of a button but, "I need to close the sidebar when i press anywhere on the screen"

I tried to use drawer from react-navigation but was not able to achieve what i wanted.

```
let width = Dimensions.get('window').width
let height = Dimensions.get('window').height

class Sample1 extends React.Component { 
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            toggleDrawer: false
        }
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            toggleDrawer: !this.state.toggleDrawer
        }))
    }

    touchAnywhere = () => {
        this.setState(() => ({
            toggleDrawer: false
        }))
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <View onPress={this.touchAnywhere}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggle}>
                    <Image
                        source={require('../../images/drawer-150x150.png')}
                    style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: "80%" }}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            { 
                this.state.toggleDrawer && (
                    <View style={styles.menu}>
                        <SideBar 
                        />
                    </View>
                )
            }
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    menu: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      position : 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      width : width * 0.8, 
      height : height,
      paddingTop : 10,
      paddingLeft : 10,
      paddingRight : 10,
      paddingBottom : 10
  },
})
```

Comment: The above code i have come up with sidebar which toggles on press of a button i need it to close when i touch anywhere on the screen

Comment: if i use anything other than view like touchableWithoutFeedback . i am getting 

" Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child." error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onPress will not work on `View`, you can wrap the `View` within `TouchableWithoutFeedback` or directly use  `TouchableWithoutFeedback` :

So instead of using `<View onPress={this.touchAnywhere}>` use `<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.touchAnywhere}>`

You can [clone the github repo](https://github.com/webdevfarhan/stackoverflow-solution-1) or see the full code below

Full Code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Dimensions,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

let width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
let height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggleDrawer: false,
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({toggleDrawer: !this.state.toggleDrawer});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.toggle}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggle}>
            <Text>Toggle Me</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          {this.state.toggleDrawer && (
            <View style={styles.menu}>
              <Text>Sidebar</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menu: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: width * 0.8,
    height: height,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Farhan, Thanks for the reply, i tried that previously, i am getting this error

Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

Comment: Thanks farhan for your time and help, this helped a lot . I have upvoted and ticked you answer.